# Hitting error when installing django-mssql 1.5

Tags: python, django, django-mssql

No clue as to what the problem is - any suggestions appreciated.

Python 3.3.1 (32-bit), Django 1.6.2, Win7 professional.

Here is the traceback:

```
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-mssql
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "c:\users\stephe~1.saw\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_stephen.sawyer\
        django-mssql\setup.py", line 115, in <module>
        version=find_version("sqlserver_ado", "__init__.py"),
      File "c:\users\stephe~1.saw\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_stephen.sawyer\
        django-mssql\setup.py", line 17, in find_version
        version_file, re.M)
      File "C:\Python33\Lib\re.py", line 161, in search
        return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
    TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "c:\users\stephe~1.saw\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_stephen.sawyer\django
-mssql\setup.py", line 115, in <module>

    version=find_version("sqlserver_ado", "__init__.py"),

  File "c:\users\stephe~1.saw\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_stephen.sawyer\django
-mssql\setup.py", line 17, in find_version

    version_file, re.M)

  File "C:\Python33\Lib\re.py", line 161, in search

    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)

TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: Looking at the error I would guess it does not work with Python 3. EDIT: see https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-mssql

Comment: Well, supposedly django-mssql 1.5 supports Django 1.6, which is the Python3-compatible version of Django, but if that's your diagnosis @Salem, I'd better check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIP sees the latest version as a pre-release, use

```
pip install django-mssql --pre
```

to install and it will work fine in python 3+.